# How to use signal from one midi track to transpose another midi track in Reaper?

Tags: midi, daw, reaper, pitch, pitch-shifting

I want to create 2 midi tracks:

First track plays some simple pattern and loops it.

In a second track I want to specify a note, which should indicate how to transpose first midi track (basically a pitch signal of some sort)

Someone knows the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for an arpeggiator.

With some plugins, you can either program a step-sequenced arpeggio, which triggers on a MIDI note event.

These will mostly be atonal/chromatic, and won't necessarily adhere to any scales that you're using.  There may be some that have this intelligence however.

Comment: thank you for a good idea, atonal arpeggiator is exactly what I was looking for!